# AMPScript to create Campaign Member

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

Using AMPscript, I need to check if the form submission is an existing SF Campaign Member. If not, I need to create a new SF campaign member record using AMPscript.

```
%%[
var @id, @row, @campaignId, @emailParam, @SfCampaign

SET @id = Id
SET @campaignId = '7012M000001JHyA'
SET @emailParam = RequestParameter('EmailAddress')


IF NOT EMPTY(@emailParam) THEN
SET @SfCampaign = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('CampaignMember', 'Id', 'Email', '=', @emailParam)

IF RowCount(@SfCampaign) > 0 THEN
      SET @row = Row(@SfCampaign, 1)
      SET @id = Field(@row, 'Id')

 ELSE

CreateSalesforceObject(
'CampaignMember', 3,
'CampaignId',@campaignId,
'ContactId',@contactId,
'Status','Sent'
)
EndIF   
]%%
```

Comment: Hi Marijana, please specify the error you are getting. Or what problem you are facing with this ampscript

Comment: Hi Nishant. I actually used the code above and am receiving error.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post the received error message verbatim.

Comment: 500 Internal Error. My code is not accurate. I am not sure what i am missing...I know I have to retrieve the Campaign Member record to see if the email submitted is related to the CampaignId. Then I would create the new object. Please help me out here. I've been trying to figure this one out all weekend.

Comment: if you comment out your CreateSalesforceObject block and output the values of `@id`, `@emailParam` and `RowCount(@SfCampaign)` what do you get?

Comment: Where is `@contactID` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `ENDIF` at the after your `CreateSalesforceObject` function call.  Secondly, looks like you're overwriting the value of `@id`.  Seems like the second instance should be `@contactID`.

Regarding my comment about outputting the values before doing the operations -- here's what I mean:

```
%%[

var @id, @row, @campaignId, @emailParam, @SfCampaign

SET @id = AttributeValue("Id")
SET @campaignId = '7012M000001JHyA'
SET @emailParam = RequestParameter('EmailAddress')

output(concat("<br>id: ", @id))
output(concat("<br>campaignId: ", @campaignId))
output(concat("<br>emailParam: ", @emailParam))

IF NOT EMPTY(@emailParam) THEN

    SET @SfCampaign = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('CampaignMember', 'Id', 'Email', '=', @emailParam)

    output(concat("<br>RowCount(@SfCampaign): ", RowCount(@SfCampaign)))

    IF RowCount(@SfCampaign) > 0 THEN

          SET @row = Row(@SfCampaign, 1)
          SET @contactId = Field(@row, 'Id')

          output(concat("<br>@contactId: ", @contactId))

    ELSE

    /* 
        CreateSalesforceObject(
        'CampaignMember', 3,
        'CampaignId',@campaignId,
        'ContactId',@contactId,
        'Status','Sent'
        )
    */

    ENDIF 

EndIF   

]%%
```

Once you've validated that you're getting the values you intend, uncomment the code and move on to the next part.  It's just the process of elimination instead of trying to make it all work at once.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That worked!